# Ubuntu kills USB 3.0 Chipset on Asus Z87-PRO motherboard

Tags: usb, uefi, asus, motherboard

I have PC based on Asus Z87-PRO Motherboard. I have installed both Windows 7 & Ubuntu 15.04.

When I have to reset Ubuntu (e.g. because of freezing) all of USB 3.0 ports stop working. Completely - I mean neither windows, nor Ubuntu, nor even UEFI see them. To get USB 3.0 working back, I have to re-upload onboard USB 3.0 controller firmware using windows application provided by Asus.

Any idea what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

@Fabby, I don't think cosmic rays had anything to do with @heemayl issue because I am having the exact same issue. I also have an Asus Z87 Pro Mobo and after I updated to Ubuntu 15.04 the top 4 USB ports stopped working. My first thought was to RMA the board, but I've been seeing reports of issues with kernel 3.19 and the ASMedia USB controller.

More digging is in order, I'll reply on this thread I am able to find anything else.

Comment: Any luck with this? I am about to reinstall the firmware to try and fix this problem.  Running Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: I ended up having to return the motherboard for a replacement. I couldn't figure out what was wrong. I put in the new mother board, and amazingly, all my problems went away. USB all works, odd OS issues I was having disappeared, everything just works again with no changes to any software or firmware. 

Don't forget, the  Asus Z87-PRO has a 3 year warranty, you just have to be able to live without it for about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue today (with Asus Z87-PRO Motherboard) in same conditions, I fixed it by :

> re-upload onboard USB 3.0 controller firmware using windows
>   application provided by Asus

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't kill your USB 3.0 Chipset. Maybe you had a voltage spike when reset or the proverbial [cosmic ray](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Cosmic_ray), or more probably: **a bug in the firmware caused the problem! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

Anyway it is a problem that was not caused by Ubuntu.

Comment: Well... I reseted this computer many times on Windows and I never had problem with that. But on Ubuntu it happens almost every time. I have both systems for almost a year. I do not believe in coincidences.

Comment: A reset has nothing to do with the running operating system.

Comment: I just reseted ubuntu and that's what happend: in GRUB mouse and keyboard (which I have connected to USB 3.0) worked. After selecting system - stopped.

Comment: Yes, ok. But as you can read in the answer " more probably: a bug in the firmware caused the problem"